# What is the equivalent of netsh wlan hostednetwork on MacOSX?

Tags: macos, network, wifi

With Windows is is possible to setup a `netsh wlan hostednetwork` even if the computer is already using a wlan connection for itself. However, a Mac's inbuilt Internet Sharing functionalities only support generating a wlan from a wired connection. What application/settings can I use to construct a wlan hostednetwork the same way it is done on Windows?

Comment: What specific criteria of the windows hosted network needs implementation? We might have tons of people that know the answer but can't share since they are unaware of what "same as Windows" means in practice. I won't downvote this, but it probably should be closed as unclear or too broad. Think of this - if you're asking someone to help you make your bile like Billy's bike - if we don't know BIlly's bike we can't begin to help you ordering a banana seat and handlebar tape.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not possible. What do you try to archive? If you have the login credentials for the network your first mac uses, you could use those on any other device to connect to the wlan. The only thing I could think of is using a mac as a repeater. Questions regarding this were answered at: [MacBook as WiFi extender](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/43977/macbook-as-wifi-extender) and [Macbook Pro as a wireless bridge? (Private hotspot from external wifi connection)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/87571/macbook-pro-as-a-wireless-bridge-private-hotspot-from-external-wifi-connection)

tl;dr: It is not possible. one solution is to use another external wifi card via usb.